# How to call a super type method?

Tags: inheritance, types, julia

I have to following exemplary type structure

```
abstract type bla end
abstract type blup <: bla end

mutable struct Ablup <: blup
   a::Real
end

mutable struct Bblup <: blup
    b::Real
end


init(obj::bla) = println("bla")
init(obj::blup) = println("blup")
init(obj::Ablup) = println("Ablup")
init(obj::Bblup) = println("Bblup")

testA = Ablup(1)
testB = Bblup(1)

init(testA)
init(testB)
```

how can I call the `bla` and `blup` implementation of `init`?
E.g. if I want to extend the super type method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `invoke` function:

```
julia> invoke(init, Tuple{bla}, testA)
bla

julia> invoke(init, Tuple{bla}, testB)
bla

julia> invoke(init, Tuple{blup}, testA)
blup

julia> invoke(init, Tuple{blup}, testB)
blup
```